# How to assign variables to nested classes in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to assign values to nested class for one outer class?

For example, let's say we have this inner classes.

```
class animal(NamedTuple)
   class dog(NamedTuple)
       name: str
       weight: int
   class cat(NamedTuple)
       color: str
       name: str
```

And I want to initialize it in another place like below, but it doesn't compile.

`AnimalDic = animal(dog(name="snoopy", weight="10"), cat(color="black", name="tom")`

Is there a way to make it possible?

Comment: This probably doesn't work as you think it does. It makes little sense. It's unclear what this is supposed to accomplish. As a rule of thumb, there's no such thing as "nested classes" in Python.

Comment: More precisely, there's usually little *reason* to use a nested class. Java has them to work around the restriction of "one class per file", which Python doesn't have.

Answer (score 2):

Don't nest them. Define the two "inner" classes before:

```
class Dog(NamedTuple):
    name: str
    weight: int

class Cat(NamedTuple):
    color: str
    name: str

class Animal(NamedTuple): 
    dog: Dog
    cat: Cat

AnimalDic = Animal(Dog(name="snoopy", weight="10"), Cat(color="black", name="tom")
```

I also fixed your casing. Don't use lower case for class names.